# JsonConvert.Serialize performance in F#

Tags: performance, serialization, f#, json.net

I create a record type as follows:

```
type CombEmp =
    {
        empid:int
        empname:string
        email:string                       
    }

let defCombEmp:CombEmp =
    {
        empid = 0
        empname = ""
        email = ""
    }
```

I then create record instances:

```
let chrE1 = {defCombEmp with empid = 100; empname = "Wayne Rooney"; email = "wroo@mun.com"}
let chrE2 = {defCombEmp with empid = 100; empname = "Wayne R"; email = "war@mun.com"}
let chrE3 = {defCombEmp with empid = 100; empname = "Wayne R"; email = "rooney@mun.com"}
```

Then I create a list of 65-70 records using above instances as so:

```
let hrLst = [|chrE1;chrE2;chrE3;chrE1;chrE2;chrE3;chrE1; ...... |] |> Array.toList
```

I have now written code as given below.

The function `GetByteCount` gets the size of serialized data (using NewtonSoft here).

The function `loop1` creates a long list of around 500k length using above `hrLst`.

The function `loop2` reduces the input sequence by 1000 in every iteration and calls `GetByteCount` for the remaining list

```
let GetByteCount data = //can improve this algorithm?
    let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
    let x = data
            |> JsonConvert.SerializeObject
            |> Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount
    stopWatch.Stop()
    Console.WriteLine("time reqd: " + stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds")
    x

let PerfTestLoop() =
    let rec loop1 ctr l =
        if ctr%100 = 0 then Console.WriteLine("" + ctr.ToString())
        match ctr with
        |500 -> l
        |_ ->
            let l2 = l @ hrLst
            loop1 (ctr+1) l2
    let l = loop1 1 hrLst
    let len = l.Length
    let s = l @ l |> List.toSeq
    Console.WriteLine("input length: " + (Seq.length s).ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("Start Measuring ..")
    let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()

    let rec loop2 ctr s =
        match ctr with
        |100 -> s |> GetByteCount
        |_ -> 
            let news = Seq.skip 2000 s        
            let size = news |> GetByteCount
            loop2 (ctr+1) news
    let x = loop2 1 s

let res =  PerfTestLoop() // becomes slow gradually
```

Observation is that the time taken for execution of `GetByteCount` in each iteration of `loop2` goes on increasing even though the size of the sequence is reducing! Why is this happening? In Task Manager, the CPU and Memory usage remains steady. Is there any other way to find the byte count of the data or to reduce the time required for executing `GetByteCount` somehow?

If in `loop2` I remove the `Seq.skip` line and use the same sequence in each iteration then the time required is similar for each iteration and doesn't vary much.

Comment: `Seq.skip` doesn't do what you think it does. It creates a new sequence, which, when enumerated, will cause the enumeration of the underlying sequence, but skip the first N elements. When you do this over and over again, you create a "nesting doll" of `Seq.skip` calls, each of which enumerates the previous, ultimately always enumerating the whole original 500K sequence.

Comment: Wow thanks, didnt know this. How then do I actually 'split' a sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible improvements to this code, but the main problem here is not understanding when to choose a list, array or seq based on their relative pros and cons in semantics and performance.

An F# list is an immutable singly linked list which is fast at quickly adding and removing items from the front. It's not fast at concatenation (the `@` operator), or accessing items at a certain index.

An F# array is a .NET array: it's mutable, and has fast index access etc. However, most F# functions for working with arrays will avoid mutation and make copies.

A `seq` is a .NET `IEnumerable<T>`. It is a sequence that you can enumerate through from beginning. The values are calculated as they are needed by the sequence consumer and may be expensive to compute. Each value could depend on previous values depending on the implementation of the `seq`, which is why if you create a new sequence with skipped values and pass it somewhere else, the new call site still needs to re-evaluate the skipped values in order to get the ones that it will actually use. One way around this in F# is to use `Seq.cache`. This will turn a normal seq into one which caches each item as it's evaluated so that repeated access does not cause recalculation.ver, most F# functions for working with arrays will avoid mutation and make copies.

---

So why do you need to use a `seq` in the first place? You have a `list` to start with, which is not lazy and therefore you're holding all this data in memory. You do `let s = l @ l |> List.toSeq`. Changing this to `List.toArray` and using `Array.skip` later on will probably make this much faster.

It would probably also help to change all of your lists to arrays too, since you're not making use of the benefits of lists. If you keep `hrLst` as an array then you can remove `loop1` entirely and just do this: `Array.replicate 500 hrLst |> Array.concat`

---

In general, I recommend that you become very familiar with the F# collections: list, array, seq, map and set. Browse the functions in these modules and their documentation as they will be useful in almost all F# code. The built in functions will usually remove the need to use recursion and result in simpler code. I suspect that `loop2` could also be replaced with some use of `Array.chunkBySize` but it's not clear to me what your code is trying to do.

Comment: Actually given above is just a kind of test code. Main aim is to divide a large seq(which is received as input) into chunks of optimized size which are within a size(in bytes) limit. This question was focused on why the execution time for `GetByteCount`  was increasing for every iteration. Thanks!

Comment: "In general, I recommend that you become very familiar with the F# collections: list, array, seq, map and set" - Any good books/links that you can recommend? That would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @ronilk Start with the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.seq-module-%5Bfsharp%5D

Comment: @ronilk [Choosing between collections functions](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/) is a good overview. Seq's implementation itself can be slow in F#. Also explore ways to parallelize via Array.Parallel or other methods (PSeq, and Nessos Streams come to mind).